# Stream a remote file with tornado and requests

Tags: python, tornado, python-requests

So basicaly what i'm trying to do is to open connection to a remote file and read it in chunks then spell it the user

using tornado as a web framework and requests for reading the remote file

here is where i got so far

```
class DefaultHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    url = 'http://domain.tld/large_file.rar'
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/force-download')
    self.set_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=large_file.rar')
    self.set_header('Content-length', r.headers.get('content-length'))
    self.set_header('Pragma', 'public')
    self.set_header('Expires', 0)
    self.set_header('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0')
    self.set_header('Cache-Controle', 'public')
    self.set_header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary')
    self.set_header('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes')
    self.set_header('Connection', 'close')
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        if chunk:
            self.write(chunk)
            self.flush()
    self.finish()
```

EDIT------------------------------------------

```
class DefaultHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
def get(self):

    url = 'http://largefilelocation'
    r = requests.Request('GET', url).prepare()
    resp = requests.Session().send(r, stream=True)

    self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/force-download')
    self.set_header('Content-Disposition', resp.headers['content-disposition'])
    self.set_header('Pragma', 'public')
    self.set_header('Expires', 0)
    self.set_header('Content-Length', int(resp.headers['content-length']))
    self.set_header('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0')
    self.set_header('Cache-Controle', 'public')
    self.set_header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary')
    self.set_header('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes')
    self.set_header('Connection', 'close')

    for chunk in self._file_stream(resp):
        self.write(chunk)
        self.flush()
    self.finish()

def _file_stream(self, resp):
    print resp.headers
    for chunk in resp.iter_lines(128):
        if not chunk: break
        yield chunk
```

Answer (score 3):

The `requests` library is synchronous, which means that it blocks the `IOLoop` whenever you use it. You have to use Tornado's `AsyncHTTPClient` instead to allow the `IOLoop` to keep running. `AsyncHTTPClient` has a `streaming_callback` option that you can use here.

Comment: Is it possible to use streaming_callback, but wait first for the response code, and handle that synchronously?

Comment: Yes, but it's a little awkward. You can pass `header_callback` with the request, and this function will be called before the first call to `streaming_callback`. This callback is passed the headers as a list of strings, starting with the status line like `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`. You'll have to parse this yourself (probably using `tornado.httputil.parse_response_start_line`)